# 'invalidationHandler called' error when posting on twitter

Tags: twitter, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to post on Twitter from my app, but I keep on getting the following error in the log

```
LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called
```

Below is my method for posting on Twitter. This method is in a `TwitterViewController` class which inherits for `UIViewController`

```
-(void)tweetHighscore  {
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting from my own app! :)"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    CCLOG(@"it's working okay");
        }
}
```

EDIT:

I set a breakpoint and it seems like `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is causing the `invalidationHandler`.